# Get token from cookie using Apollo Client and Next-Auth

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, next-auth

can you help to check my code is there anyway that i can get access token from cookie and send it through apollo client? In my Next.js project i am using NextAuth for authentication. After user logged in I save user information and access token inside session. But i have know idea how can i get it and pass it with apollo client.

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import { ApolloClient, ApolloLink, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client'
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { concatPagination } from '@apollo/client/utilities'
import merge from 'deepmerge'
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual'

export const APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME = '__APOLLO_STATE__'

let apolloClient

const CLIENT_URL =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? process.env.API_END_POINT
    : 'http://localhost:1337'

function createApolloClient() {
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: `${CLIENT_URL}/graphql`,
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  });

  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
      }
    }
  });

  const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          jobs: concatPagination(),
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    srMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache
  });

  return client;

}

export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient()

  // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial state
  // gets hydrated here
  if (initialState) {
    // Get existing cache, loaded during client side data fetching
    const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract()

    // Merge the existing cache into data passed from getStaticProps/getServerSideProps
    const data = merge(initialState, existingCache, {
      // combine arrays using object equality (like in sets)
      arrayMerge: (destinationArray, sourceArray) => [
        ...sourceArray,
        ...destinationArray.filter((d) =>
          sourceArray.every((s) => !isEqual(d, s))
        ),
      ],
    })

    // Restore the cache with the merged data
    _apolloClient.cache.restore(data)
  }
  // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient
  // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
  if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient

  return _apolloClient
}

export function addApolloState(client, pageProps) {
  if (pageProps?.props) {
    pageProps.props[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME] = client.cache.extract()
  }

  return pageProps
}

export function useApollo(pageProps) {
  const state = pageProps[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME]
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(state), [state])
  return store
}
```

Comment: Can't you modify your `useApollo` function to expect a cookie and then pass it when making the call?

Comment: @juliomalves could you give me a sample? I am new to GraphQL

Comment: You could use any library like `universal-cookies` and do a `new Cookies()` (basically like you would do in any React based app). Client-side, this will get the cookies from the browser. Can you please clarify the context here (client or server rendering)? Because server-side you can get cookies from the request and pass them as params, it's a bit more complicated but not much.

Comment: hi @EricBurel it client side. it will get cookie from browser.

Comment: So yeah you can just get it as usual using the normal browser API: https://unlyed.github.io/next-right-now/reference/folder-structure

Comment: hi @july77, could you solve this some how?

Comment: Nextauth uses a http only cookie for the session token, this approach will not work